# CSV file format to import Term sets with URL field.

Tags: sharepoint-server, term-set

How to import Term sets using .CSV file with URL field.

I use below format...It works but that not contain url field...
[image]

Comment: There is no url field in termstore , you can directly add url in termstore csv file in last level

Comment: I try this but its not work

Answer (score 1):

I uploaded url as shown in image[image: Csv file]

[image: Term store set]

[image: CSV file]

Answer (score 0):

In this example you can see a sample .csv file i imported a few weeks ago.
The bold things are the header in your .csv and below you see the first row of the Metadata to import.

**Term Store;Term Group;Term Set;LCID;Level 1 Term;Level 2 Term;Level 3 Term;Level 4 Term;EN;EN Synonyms;EN Description;DE;DE Synonyms;DE Description;Available for Tagging;Link;Item Type;Path**

TEST;Metadata;Country;1033;EG;;;;;;;;;;;;;https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com;